# Reason for a certain image not showing on server, but it does on local?

Tags: css, image, server, local

So I'm building a website with the following setup: plain HTML/CSS, Bootstrap and Gulp. I've developed locally, everything went well, all images are showing. I've uploaded all the files on my server and one image just does not want to show.

```
.hm-hero {
    background: url("../img/main_pic.jpg") no-repeat top center;
    background-size: contain;
    min-height: 600px;
    padding-top: 28px;
}



.hm-signup {
    min-height: 338px;
    background: url("../img/signup-img.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Both these images are showing on localhost, but when uploaded to a server the bottom one doesn't. Both files in the same directory. Permission for all image files is 644.

What other problem should I look into when it comes to these situations? I just can't explain this to myself, there is no typo, could this be a server problem?

Comment: The url has to be relative path. please change background Url torelative path on server

Comment: Clear your cache? Re-upload the broken image?

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Console actually says "[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (signup-img.jpg, line 0)".
Interesting, because I have the image set to www.xyz.com/xy/img/signup-img.jpg, but in console the error points to www.xyz.com/img/signup-img.jpg . How can I fix this? I have the image uploaded in the correct path.

Comment: That means the image isn't in the location you specified.

Comment: Just added more to my reply.

Comment: @shacks that's what I'm trying to say. remove those .. and updates with URL

Comment: I do not want to use absolute paths, I need to figure out why one image works and the second one doesn't. This makes no sense.

Comment: If I go to the absolute path in my web browser, the image shows, so it's there. Path is www.xyz.com/xy/img/signup-img.jpg .
Index.html is in xy folder.

Comment: `../` means go up one folder

Comment: yea, that is fine, I have separate css and img folders, so I need to go one up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I was being downvoted, but I've found the answer to my problem. The last image that is not showing had a path modified after the first upload and it all has to do with CACHING. I'm also using Cloudfare so that might be a problem too. So in case images are not showing when uploaded to server, check CACHING. Siteground for example have a tool in cPanel of SuperCacher and that must be disabled.

Comment: That's right, credit goes to you. Still, browser cache was not enough.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have deployed the imags to server and base URL of your site is www.xyz.com, then your background URL has to be this.

```
 .hm-hero {
        background: url("www.xyz.com/img/main_pic.jpg") no-repeat top center;
        background-size: contain;
        min-height: 600px;
        padding-top: 28px;
    }



    .hm-signup {
        min-height: 338px;
        background: url("www.xyz.com/img/signup-img.jpg");
        background-size: contain;
    }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Relative paths are perfectly valid.

Comment: @j08691 FYI - best way to use is relative path. See this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: Your answer uses an **absolute** path, not a relative one